# Unable to connect to my newly created MySQL server in Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, firewall, azure-database-mysql

After creating a new server in the Azure Database for MySQL service, I get the following error when trying to connect to it. The server has been created since I see a notification on the Azure portal to the effect and can also view the server details on the Azure portal.

*Client with IP address `<ipv4 address>` is not allowed to access the server.*

Am I missing any steps in making my MySQL server accessible to my client (mysqlexe/mysql workbench)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the error message, you are unable to connect to your MySQL server in Azure because the firewall rules are not setup correctly to allow your IP address to access the server. As a result, your app/client cannot connect to the newly created server. Read more about [firewall settings in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules) and use either the [portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-cli) to manage firewall rules for your newly created MySQL server. Once you have setup firewall rules correctly, you should be able to connect to the server.